# How to redirect to a page in the same open tab in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to move to home.html page,if login gets successful. But this home.html page gets appended in the same login.html page. I want only home.html to be displayed rather than apending to the same page. Here  is my code -

app.js -

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'myApp.filters',
'myApp.services',
'myApp.directives',
'myApp.controllers'
).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});
}]);
```

controller.js -

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('loginForm', function($scope,  $location) {
  $scope.users = [{name: "Neha", pwd: "Neha"}, {name: "Sneha", pwd: "Sneha"}];
  $scope.login = function (userName, password) {
    if (userName === "Neha" && password === "Neha") {
        alert("Welcome");
                    $location.path("/home");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Login");
    }
  }
 });
```

**login.html** -

```
<body>
 <h1 class="title">EXPENSE SHARER MANAGER</h1>
  <div class="mainBdy" ng-controller="loginForm">
  <form ng-submit="login(userName, password)">
    <div class="userName">
      <label for="usrNm">USERNAME</label>
      <input type="text" id="usrNm" ng-model="userName"/>
    </div>
    <div class="password">
      <label for="pwd">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" ng-model="password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="btnSection">
      <button>LOGIN</button>
      <button>SIGN UP</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**home.html** -

```
 <body>
  <h1 class="title">EXPENSE SHARER MANAGER</h1>
 </body>
```

Please guide me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Share your html outline for login and home.

Comment: Updated the question with the html outline of login and home.

Comment: Are these pages partials that are used in  `ng-view`? AngularJS is a SPA framework. Have you gone through the constructs like `ng-view`, `routes` etc.